# Get all session-cached objects in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, grails-orm

I have a method which executes HQL using `org.hibernate.Query.executeUpdate()` and changes some rows in a database. If some of affected by the query rows were previously loaded into the current session (e.g. using `Session.get()`), they are now stale and need refreshing.

But I want that method to be independent of a previous work with the session, and not to track all loaded objects that might be affected in order to refresh them afterwards. Is it possible with Hibernate to retrieve and iterate through objects in the 1-level cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the following solution for the issue, which works for me:

```
Map.Entry<Object,EntityEntry>[] entities = ((SessionImplementor)session).getPersistenceContext().reentrantSafeEntityEntries()
```